# Добраться до компонентов ItemRenderer в List

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Есть вот такая структура.

1) Надобно сделать сохранение и загрузку положений слайдеров. Не знаю как получить доступ сразу ко всем (шести) слайдерам, чтобы получить их значения.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable] private var namesLabel:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        protected function group1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            listSlider.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, addValue, false, 0, true);

            namesLabel.addItem("Red"); 
            namesLabel.addItem("Green");
            namesLabel.addItem("Blue");
            namesLabel.addItem("Contrast");
            namesLabel.addItem("Saturation"); 
            namesLabel.addItem("Lightness");
        }

        protected function addValue(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {   
            if (String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) == "+") {
                event.target.value += 0.01;
            }

            if (String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) == "-") {
                event.target.value -= 0.01;
            }

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup>
    <s:Button  label="Reset" toolTip="Reset"/>
</s:HGroup>

<s:List  id="listSlider" dataProvider="{namesLabel}" >
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <components:SliderComponent id="slider" sliderName="{data}"/>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

**components:SliderComponent:**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable] public var sliderName:String = "";
        [Bindable] public var sliderValue:Number = 1;

        protected function changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            this.sliderValue = slider.value;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup toolTip="{this.sliderName}">
    <s:Label  id="labelShortName" text="{this.sliderName.charAt(0)}" />
    <s:HSlider  id="slider" value="{sliderValue}" minimum="0" maximum="2" snapInterval="0.01" change="changeHandler(event)" />
    <s:Label  id="labelValue" text="{slider.value}" width="25" />
</s:HGroup>
```

2) Еще проблема. Когда фокус стоит на списке. Выбираем мышкой слайдер под именем "R" ("Red") и нажимаем кнопки "+", "-" - все нормально, прибавляются значения у "R". Теперь нажмем клавишу "L", то выбор в списке переключится на последний слайдер с именем "L" ("Lightness"). И если нажимать на клавиши "+", "-" - то фокус стоит все еще на слайдере "R", и естественно прибавляются значения у него, а не у "L". Как поменять фокус при изменении выделенного элемента в листе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
// исходный объект для данных чутка усложняем
namesLabel.addItem({name:"Red", value:10});
// добавляем в ArrayCollection более сложный объект с полем для значения слайдера
namesLabel.addItem({name:"5Red5", value:15});
listSlider.dataProvider = namesLabel;
// Убираем объявления внутри родительского списка
<s:List id="listSlider" itemRenderer="components.SliderComponent"/>
// Внутри ItemRender
protected function changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    this.sliderValue = slider.value;
    data.value = slider.value; // Сохраняем значение
}
// Вносим данные в ItemRender       
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    labelShortName.text = data.name;
    slider.value = data.value;
}
```

Теперь в namesLabel будет сохранятся значение для каждого слайдера.

```
 for each ( var o:Object in namesLabel )
 {
     trace( o.value );
 }
```

По второму вопросу: (проверять не буду)
Попробуйте ставить фокус менеджером внутри ItemRender.

```
focusManager.setFocus( slider);
```

Comment: По первому вопросу - уже сделал точно так же.
А со вторым - будем пробовать. Спасибо за направление куда копать :)